# Updating closed Access database with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a macro in Excel to delete tables in Access.

Is there is a way to do this without opening the Access database?

```
Set AppAcc = Nothing
Set AppAcc = New Access.Application                         
AppAcc.Visible = True

AppAcc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\MyStuff\MyDataBase.mdb"

AppAcc.DoCmd.SetWarnings False

With AppAcc        
   .DoCmd.OpenQuery "Delete_Query1"

   .DoCmd.OpenQuery "Delete_Query2"

   .DoCmd.OpenQuery "Delete_Query3"     
End With

AppAcc.DoCmd.SetWarnings True
AppAcc.Quit acQuitSaveNone

Set AppAcc = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, there is a way. Since MS Access is a database it can connect via a backend like all major RDBMS's (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.). Below demonstrates ODBC/OLEDB connections using ADO. Then, further below is an alternative version with DAO which you are currently running but can do so without `Access.Application` and `DoCmd` calls.

Both should even work without having MS Access GUI (the MS Office app) installed. Each use late binding. For early binding, add VBA references *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects #.# Library* or *Microsoft DAO #.# Object Library*, then modify `Dim` and `Set` statements.

**ADO**

```
Dim conn As Object

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' WITH ODBC DRIVER
conn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=C:\MyStuff\MyDataBase.mdb;"

' WITH ODBC DSN
'conn.Open "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\MyStuff\MyDataBase.mdb;"

' WITH OLEDB PROVIDER
'conn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyStuff\MyDataBase.mdb;" 

' THREE WAYS TO CALL ACTION QUERIES
conn.Execute "{CALL Delete_Query1}"
conn.Execute "EXEC Delete_Query2"
conn.Execute "Delete_Query3"

Set conn = Nothing
```

**DAO**

```
Dim conn As Object, db As Object

Set conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:\MyStuff\MyDataBase.mdb")

db.Execute "Delete_Query1"
db.Execute "Delete_Query2"
db.Execute "Delete_Query3"

Set db = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: @Parfait.............Thank you very much for this information.  It was very helpful and helped me solve my issue.  Thanks again.......

Comment: Great. Thanks @ryguy72!